# OpenTok: Video Element Paused warning, can't unpublish

Tags: live-streaming, opentok

I'm trying to unpublish a video but keep getting the warning

```
"Video element paused, auto-resuming. If you intended to do this, use publishVideo(false) or subscribeToVideo(false) instead."
```

I'm unpublishing with:

```
clientPublisher.publishAudio(false);
clientPublisher.publishVideo(false);
clientSession.unpublish(clientPublisher, handleError);
```

The "streamDestoryed" function is firing so it seems like it should be unpublished.  But if I subscribe to it using:

```
o.subscriber = clientSession.subscribe(stream, vid, {... subscribeToAudio: false...}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
  }
  else {
     o.subscriber.subscribeToAudio(false);
  }
}
```

I still get audio.  What exactly does this message mean and how do I stop publishing?

EDIT:
If I subscribe first WITHOUT audio, I can toggle it on and off and it works fine.  However, if the client publishes and I don't set subscribeToAudio to false, I can no longer toggle the audio on and off... it's always on.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to unpublishAudio and unpublishVideo. Just the unpublish should take care of everything. Then if the stream is destroyed you shouldn’t be able to subscribe to it at all. Are you subscribing to yourself in the same browser window or using a separate window?

Comment: I just added those because the clientSession.unpublish didn't seem to work.  The client is on an entirely different computer.